# Declined flags for posts not being in English

Tags: support

I would like the moderator who declined my flags to answer me this question:

- If my code is correct, or looks be correct, can I write my answer in Afrikaans as English is not my native tongue?

My question relates to the two answers to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/194289/31545)

### EDIT

What is quite evident here is that we have serious issues on this stack, we cannot see eye to eye regarding our on and off topic policy, and it now seems that the English-only policy is also a debate now as non English answers are now also accepted.

Don't let this become a joke, and don't let we all as WPSE become the laughing stock of the SE network.

### EDIT 2

One of the flags I have raised to the answers not being in English

> Answer is not in English, therefor not understandible

This is the response I got to the flag

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Comment: Please keep the dramatics in check a bit. :) These are just routine issues in perspective. They are a challenges to be worked through, but not the end of the world/stack.

Comment: It is really laughable though

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the long established [Non-English Question Policy](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) still stands.

The questions (and by extension answers, as well as content in general) *must* be in English. With obvious exception of some newer stacks with different "main" language.

I am not following what your specific flag situation was, but this covers your question literally.

Comment: Just to note, I really appreciate your feedback on this issue, :-). This was actually targeted at the mod who declined the flags ;-)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I have declined it because there was nothing I could do as a moderator that couldn't be done by someone else. One post has already a comment regarding the language, and it is the accepted answer, the other one contains the real solution. I didn't want to delete that information, because it might be more valuable than the text around it.

But yes, I agree, this is a messy situation. If someone who speaks Spanish better than I do just would an edit, that would be the best solution.

Comment: For a newby that does not speak or understand that language, that answers is really useless. In my opinion, it is really the same as just dumping code as an answer because I really do not understand wat the hell is written there, so I have to rely on the code. Where do we draw a line? Do we just sit back and allow code only answers (because this is in essence what it is to me) or foreign, no-making-sense languages, or do we take action and delete them. Excellent code is still totally useless for newbies without some kind of explanation

Comment: Also, the one user was asked to rewrite the answer in English which he decided to ignore, so clearly, he feels nothing for policies